# Android Things Infrared implementaton with LIRC

Tags: android, infrared, android-things, lirc

I know LIRC works on a Raspberry Pi, however, I want to know if LIRC will work with Google's Android Things. If not, I want to know is there is anyway to communicate with Infrared sensors and decode the infrared signal.

Comment: the infrared sensor will use PWM right? Do you have a sensor in mind, or the datasheet for it? https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/pwm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately seems not: there is no IrDA section in [SDK Pripherial IO](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/index.html) and [max frequency of GPIO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41727580/6950238) lines does not allow implement it via "bitbang" mode. But You can use Android Things board UART and IrDA protocol stack controllers like [mcp2155](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21690B.pdf) as in [that](http://www.societyofrobots.com/electronics_irda_tutorial.shtml) project. Also [that](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3024) notes may be useful. When support of USB IrDA devices will be implemented in Android Things or the source code of Android Things becomes available, then you can use USB-IrDA dongles like [that](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004GED7SI).