# open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR) returns -1

Tags: android-things

I am trying to port https://github.com/jazzycamel/ws28128-rpi to android things using a native app.

At runtime, the library fails here.  It appears we need super user access, is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems port of WS2812 RGB LED library to Android Things platform is impossible now, even if you fix runtime error, because max frequency of RPI GPIO with Android Things is about 3kHz (for details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42282466/6950238) answer) but data transfer frequency for WS2812 RGB LED (according [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LED/WS2812.pdf)) is about 800kHz (TH+TL = 1.25us). There is no possibility now to create pulse with 0.32us duration on Android Things RPI even with native C code.